# Attribute error with super in Kivy/Python

Tags: python, kivy, super, attributeerror, kivy-language

Here is the exerpt of my code on the .py side that cause the problem:

```
class ScreenMath(Screen):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(ScreenMath,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.anchmath.ids.grdmath.ids.score.text = str("Score:" + "3")
```

And the .kv side:

```
<ScreenMath>:
    AnchorLayout:
        id: "anchmath"
        ...    
        GridLayout:
            id: "grdmath"
            ...
            Button:
                id: "score"
```

When I run the code, an AttributeError occurs :

```
    File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 841, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

As you saw, I want to change the text of my value (3 will later be a variable) when the screen in initiated, but maybe there is a better way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem - AttributeError

```
    File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 841, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

## Root Cause

Kivy was not able to find the attribute because the `id`s in your kv file were assigned string values.

## Solution

The following changes are required to solve the problem.

1. `id`s in kv file are not string. Therefore, remove double quote from `id`.
2. Replace `self.ids.anchmath.ids.grdmath.ids.score.text` with `self.ids.score.text`.

[Kv language » Referencing Widgets](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets)

> **Warning**
>
> When assigning a value to id, remember that the value isn’t a string.
>   There are no quotes: good -> id: value, bad -> id: 'value'

[Kv language » self.ids](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code)

> When your kv file is parsed, kivy collects all the widgets tagged with
>   id’s and places them in this self.ids dictionary type property. That
>   means you can also iterate over these widgets and access them
>   dictionary style:
>
> ```
> for key, val in self.ids.items():
>     print("key={0}, val={1}".format(key, val))
> ```

### Snippet - Python code

```
class ScreenMath(Screen):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(ScreenMath,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.score.text = str("Score:" + "3")
```

## Snippet- kv file

```
<ScreenMath>:
    AnchorLayout:
        id: anchmath
        ...    
        GridLayout:
            id: grdmath
            ...
            Button:
                id: score
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Comment: What is the difference between __init__() and on_pre_enter()?

Comment: By the way, I just tested it and it didn't work. Same AttributeError with 'super'

Comment: Please refer to my updated post with explanation and solution.

Comment: @Artemyx widget referencing is already right, no need to change the way of referencing widget. Just change the id to non-string as suggested.